# ThreeJS: Creating a background image that exactly fits the window?

Tags: three.js

In ThreeJS (JavaScript/ WebGL) how can I create a static background image that is part of the scene but resizes to fit the full inner browser window exactly? It works when I use CSS but then the background image won't show when making a "screenshot" via renderer.domElement.toDataURL('image/png'), which I want to. Thanks!

Comment: Will you camera be static in the scene, or will it be able to move? Have you thought about trying to make a skybox?

Comment: Which type of renderer do you use?

Comment: Cory, I currently have a static camera. I'm putting a textured box at the back of the scene, but don't know which dimensions to give the box to be exactly filling the screen with its texture. Danny, I'm using WebGLRenderer. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried a THREE.Sprite with useScreenCoordinates = true and scale it so it fits and render it in first/lowest scene?

Answer (score 14):

You can use a separate background scene to render the background image.

```
var bg = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2, 0),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: backgroundTexture})
);

// The bg plane shouldn't care about the z-buffer.
bg.material.depthTest = false;
bg.material.depthWrite = false;

var bgScene = new THREE.Scene();
var bgCam = new THREE.Camera();
bgScene.add(bgCam);
bgScene.add(bg);
```

Then in your render loop, draw bgScene before your real scene.

```
renderer.autoClear = false;
renderer.clear();
renderer.render(bgScene, bgCam);
renderer.render(scene, cam);
```

Comment: not working to me, am using `OBJMTLLode`r, without this working fine, what suppose to do for the `OBJMTLLoder` and `OBJLoder` ???

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear for me if you are trying to make a panorama viewer or something like that...

If that was your goal, here's an answer I gave to solve the problem of inserting an equirectangular image to the rendered sphere (which can be controlled by mouse and/or deviceOrientation[accelerometer in smartphones]):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37129356/1920145